# Question regarding Präsens (repeated condtions)

Tags: meaning, verb-usage, grammar-identification, time

In German and also in English people use Präsens to express something that happens regularly right?

I have seen something like:

> "Wir helfen anderen Menschen, die alles verloren haben."

but I have also seen sentences like:

> "Wir liefern die Ware, die man im Internet/auf unserer Webseite
>   bestellt/bestellt hat."

In this case, both ways of writing (die man bestellt/die man bestellt hat) are correct no? Same case with:

> "Wir helfen Menschen, die ihr Haustier verlieren/verloren haben."

Beides geht oder? Could you please explain me the difference between the two?

Vielen Dank!

Extra:

> "Ich freue mich immer sehr, wenn ich ein gutes Thema finde/gefunden habe, weil ich es dann meinen Studenten zeigen kann."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both variants are possible, but they describe a different thing.

- If you used *Präsens* in both parts, you focus on future repetition. That is because *Präsens* is about the present and the future.
- If you used *Präsens* and *Perfekt* (or *Präteritum* as a replacement for *Perfekt*) you focus on the line of events for each single installment.

Most times people won't make a difference nor use one or the other option consciously. Seasoned writers certainly do, however.

Sometimes it makes a difference in everyday situations, though:

> Wir helfen Menschen, die ihr Haustier verloren haben.

*First, someone loses her pet. Then, we help. We do that again and again.*

> Wir helfen Menschen, die ihr Haustier verlieren.

*Someone loses her pet. We help. We do that again and again.*

See how the latter form implies someone loses her pet **again and again**? The other option is even more nasty:

*Someone **will** lose her pet. We help. We do that again and again.*

Why is that so? Because *Präsens* is about the present **and the future**.

*We know you will lose your pet. Again and again.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94943/discussion-on-answer-by-janka-question-regarding-prasens-repeated-condtions).